# Change color animation Android

Tags: android

Sorry for my simple question, I need change color of animation navigation drawer to white.

[image]

I tried to change the styles of App, change the color features in the toolbar, but nothing works. Someone know how can I make this?

Comment: please post your style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="color">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If Api level is 21 or above, you can use:

```
drawer.getDrawable().setTint(color);
```

Auto animation:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(0xff000000, 0xffffffff);
    animator.setDuration(10000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int color = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            drawer.getDrawable().setTint(color);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
```

or changing tint follow drawer position:

```
drawer.getDrawable().setTint(0xff000000 + (movePosition / maxDistance) * (0xffffffff - 0xff000000));
```

Comment: for older version use nineoldanimation library